# Zork look-a-like written in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, adventure-game

I've been working on a a text based game with a very simple battling system. There are way to many questions I can ask to get reviewed about this project, but I'll take small steps at a time (this is my first post).

I'm mostly concerned about how I handle command input and the execution of said commands within the game. Just to give a simple example of what a command might look like:

```
go north

go - command (called action in the code, as Command is the whole class)
north (and anything after that) - arguments, you most likely know about these
```

### INPUT

Currently, I've made it work using the `readline` package from Node. The input is being sent to a "commander" where it is parsed, made into a `Command` which will in the end be passed to an "executor" which will execute the command. Here's the code:

```js
//Player.ts
import readline from 'readline';
//other imports...

class Player extends Entity {
    // fields, constructor and other methods...
    
    async getInput(questionPrompt?: string): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
            const prompt = readline.createInterface({
                input: process.stdin,
                output: process.stdout,
            });

            const question = (questionPrompt) ? questionPrompt : ">";

            prompt.question(question, (answer) => {
                prompt.close()

                resolve(answer);
            })
        })
    }
}

export default Player;
```

```js
//commander.ts (technically it's inside commander/index.ts)
import Command from '../models/Command';
import Player from '../models/Player';

const actions = ['go', 'look', 'take', 'equip', 'inventory', 'help'];

export const parse = (text: string): (Command | null) => {
    const action = text.split(' ')[0];
    const args = text.split(' ').slice(1);

    if (!actions.find((a) => action === a))
        return null;

    return new Command(action, args);
}

export const execute = (command: Command, receiver: Player) => {
    switch (command.action) {
        case 'go':
            const success = receiver.move(command.args[0]);
            if (success) {
                return console.log(`You have entered a new room.\n${receiver.currentRoom.getDescription()}`);
            } else {
                return console.log(`You can't go there. Please try another one.`);
            }
        case 'look':
            const text = `You are in ${receiver.currentRoom.name}.\n` +
                `${receiver.currentRoom.description}`;
            return console.log(text);
        case 'take':
            const item = receiver.currentRoom.takeItem(command.args[0]);
            if (item)
                return receiver.takeItem(item);
            else
                return console.log(`A ${command.args[0]} couldn't be found.`);
        case 'equip':
            return receiver.inventory.map((i) => {
                if (i.name === command.args[0]) {
                    receiver.equip(i.id);
                }
            })
        case 'inventory':
            return console.log(receiver.inventory);
        case 'help':
            return console.log("No help for now... Maybe later?");
        default:
            console.log('Command error.');
            return console.log(command);
    }
}

export default {
    parse,
    execute,
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is an appropriate way to handle this use case, but this is all I could come up with. The other solution I managed to think of was to have the different commands in a separate folder where I could have them as modules and I could try to import them. This way they can maybe be classes and have their own help messages which will also make it easier to document the commands. The reason I decided to stick with this approach is because it seems a bit easier, and having the commands as separate modules kinds seems overkill to me, maybe I'm totally wrong.

I know I've probably missed something very important, so a link to the whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/Federlizer/zuul-game/tree/8ff93ac48027dd6ba4d4f85d52fe5d451e983775).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experiences in MUDs and text games, I think you would do well to create a class/module that handles each command then inject them into your processor (even manually). It will help a lot with the maintainability but also isolating commands.

```
import {registerLook} from "./commands/look";
import {registerGo} from "./commands/go";

// Build up a hash of commands. With a MUD style, you would register the shorten
// versions also (so look registers as "l", "lo", "loo", and "look") but removes
// entries that would have a conflict (so "left" would remove the "l" for look but
// register "le", "lef", and "left".
let commands = {};

registerLook(commands);
registerGo(commands);

// Then when you are running the command.
if (command.action in commands
{
  commands[command.action].run(command, receiver);
}
else
{
  // Show error of missing command
}
```

You could go further with the SOLID implementation by having the commands injected from the top-level, but the main reason for doing this is to let you have the complex logic for the commands moved into a separate file that does one thing only (Single Responsibility Principle) while treating the switch of the commands against an interface (functions inserted into the hash by a register).

Ideally, having a DI figure out the commands would be nice, but I haven't found a good DI system for Typescript I like. (You could also scan the `commands` directory and inject the commands that way.)

It also lets you nest the commands if you need to. So if you have `look at` and `look into`, you could have `commands/look.ts` break apart the first word and then pass it into look commands (`commands/look/at.ts`) to further isolate it. Or whatever makes sense.